# system like keywords such as failure, true, closed, "unable to" highlighted when processed as values for a query

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

I wrote a query to identify the total unique number of records that contain specific keywords such as "failure of cardiac valve prosthesis","true cleft rt av valve leaflet","false bundle-branch block syndrome". But when I ran it on a Linux server, these keywords were highlighted in different colors! So I am curious to know if they were highlighted because linux considered them as special commands and that this maybe affect the final results?

Here is the code:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/INDEXED_Repository/_search -d '{"query": 
{"constant_score": {"filter" : {"terms" : {"description" : ["adam attack 
stokes","adam stokes attacks","adam-stokes attacks", "failure of cardiac 
valve prosthesis","true cleft rt av valve leaflet","false bundle-branch 
block syndrome","attacks adam-stokes","attacks stokes-adams","morgagni\\s 
disease","morgagni-adam\\s stokes syndrome","morgagni-stokes-adams","spens\\ 
syndrome", and more than 10000 keywords]}}}}}'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you using, Bash/Zsh/something else?

Comment: @AlexOtt I am using bash

Comment: Can you post a snap.

Comment: @HatimStovewala posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are bash reserved words. That won't affect your output.